# Binomial form of $\frac{A(A+1) \cdots (A+n-2)}{(s+A-1)(s+A-2) \cdots (s+A-i+1)}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, infinite-product

I am attempting to place the following finite product of terms into a binomial, for example:
$$A'=\frac{A(A+1) \cdots (A+n-2)}{(s+A-1)(s+A-2) \cdots (s+A-n+1)}$$

I recognise the product on the numerator goes to $n-2$, which may look like
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}(A+i)$$
and the product on the numerator becomes the following
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(s+A-i)$$

And combining the two I then have
$$A' = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}(A+i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(s+A-i)}$$

For the binomial form, I get the following
$$A' = \frac{\binom{A+n-2}{n-2}}{\binom{s+A-n+1}{-n+1}}$$

The text from which I got this from, shows the binomial form to be
$$\frac{\binom{n+A-2}{n-1}}{\binom{s+A-1}{n-1}}$$

The denominator does not look correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator of $A'$ is just $$A(A+1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (A+n-2) = \frac{(A+n-2)!}{(A-1)!}.$$  Similarly, the denominator of $A'$ is
$$(s+A-1)(s+A-2)\cdot \ldots \cdot (s+A-n+1) = \frac{(s+A-1)!}{(s+A-n)!}.$$

So we must have
$$A' = \frac{(A+n-2)!}{(A-1)!} \frac{(s+A-n)!}{(s+A-1)!}.$$

Now for a binomial coefficient of the form $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!},$$ we must have the denominator arguments adding up to the numerator; i.e., $k + (n-k) = n$.  So one way to achieve this is to write

$$\frac{(A+n-2)!}{(A-1)!} = \frac{(A+n-2)!}{(A-1)!(n-1)!} (n-1)! = \binom{A+n-2}{n-1} (n-1)!, \\ \frac{(s+A-n)!}{(s+A-1)!} = \frac{(s+A-n)!(n-1)!}{(s+A-1)!} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} = \frac{1}{\binom{s+A-1}{n-1}} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}.$$

Therefore
$$A' = \frac{\binom{A+n-2}{n-1}}{\binom{s+A-1}{n-1}}.$$
Hence

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am still working through this. Can you explain why the denominator is the reason they are for the first two binomials? I will have to revise binomial coefficients again, but from what I recognise, when $(s+A - n)$ we set this term in the denominator, when decreasing $n$, otherwise, $(s+A+n)$ we set this in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you, I have read through the entire explanation and understand the final binomial

Comment: I have a comment on this binomial form $\frac{(s+A-1)!}{(s+A-n)!}$, how is this represented in pochammer notation, will this be $\frac{1}{(s+A-1)_n}$?